# Error inflating class TextView Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class TextView

Tags: java, android, xml, android-recyclerview, textview

I was getting That error.

```
08-21 18:19:11.607 2944-2944/com.example.android.testingrecyclerview E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.android.testingrecyclerview, PID: 2944
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class TextView
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class TextView
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 4: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x1010099 a=1}
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:459)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:771)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:704)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:76)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:72)
```

...

When Trying to inflate a TextView, later on i found out that removing the android theme fixed the issue, does anyone know why this happens?

```
    <style name="list_item_style">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">24sp</item>
    <item name="android:theme">@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium</item>
```

Does this mean we can't use themes on TextViews when using REcyclerView?

Comment: Exception seems to be an error in your XML file. Please check your xml file first

Comment: Can you post the XML of the `TextView` in question?

Comment: `   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/word"
       style="@style/list_item_style" />`

Answer (score 0):

This is the definition of `Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium`:

```
<style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/abc_text_size_medium_material</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">?android:attr/textColorSecondary</item>
</style>
```

as you can see it defines `textSize` and `textColor`.  
But your style has already defined `textSize` by this:

```
<item name="android:textSize">24sp</item>
```

Could be a conflict.